# How do I activate a virtual environment in Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, flask, virtualenv

I currently need to work on a flask project, to do that, I need to activate a virtual environment for my project. Virtual environment has already been installed at Python37\Scripts folder, but each time I want to activate the virtual environment by running `C:\Users\user\Desktop\flask-intro\venv\Scripts>activate`. `<flask-intro is my project folder>`. I get an error that says 'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. What could be the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+activate

Answer (score 3):

1. To Create and activate a Virtual Env for project on windows, navigate to your project directory on your command line window and run the following commands

   - To create - `python -m venv your-env-name`
   - To activate - `your-env-name\Scripts\activate.bat`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide full path to the script, it's enough to use like this: `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate` and it should be activated.

Also you can check this page for more details about it: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#activate-script